# What model was used here?

Tags: regression

In the wikipedia page about curve fitting:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting

The graphic on the right shows:

"Fitting of a noisy curve by an asymmetrical peak model, with an iterative process (Gauss–Newton algorithm with variable damping factor α)."

I would like to do this and I know how the algorithm works, I just don't know what mathematical model they used to fit the curve. It doesn't look like a basic polynomial.

Does anyone have any idea of the function used?

What other functions can I use to fit an asymmetric pulse?

Can anyone provide a link where different functions for different shapes are listed (so I can take my pick for any situation)?

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Regression_pic_assymetrique.gif

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Regression_pic_gaussien_dissymetrique_bruite.svg gives the explicit function -- it's just two Gaussian curves with different scales on each side of the mode.